# Is it better to compute a ROC curve using predicted probabilities or distances from the separating hyperplane?

Tags: scikit-learn, roc

My question is motivated in part by the possibilities afforded by `scikit-learn`.  In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html), there are [two](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html) of how to compute a Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve.

One uses [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) to

> Compute probabilities of possible outcomes for samples [...].

, while the other uses [`decision_function`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function), which yields the

> Distance of the samples X to the separating hyperplane.

When should each one be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543137/whats-the-difference-between-predict-proba-and-decision-function-in-sklearn-py

Comment: Be aware that questions should be self-contained. We don't want someone to have to navigate to a link & read the page to understand what you are asking. Moreover, most people on CV are unlikely to automatically know what ideas are being referenced by `predict_proba` & `decision_function`, so people won't necessarily know that this is about 2 different strategies, or what the strategies are.

Comment: @gung: (in reply to the last comment) Thank you, very good point. It's hopefully more self-contained now. It was about the middle ground: which method to use, but most importantly why. Hopefully it's ok'ish now. There is no need for apologies, as your comments so far helped to make it more appropriate

Comment: I am retracting my close vote. I now believe this question is on topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering this from a pragmatic perspective, simply by looking at code and deducing from examples. A more theoretic answer could be a great supplement.

Generally both can be used. The difference is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543137/whats-the-difference-between-predict-proba-and-decision-function-in-sklearn-py).

Yet most relevant, not all algorithms offer both `predict_proba` and `decision_function`. To my knowledge, every classifiers allows `predict_proba` in sklearn. For some - specifically SVC (Support Vector Classification) - both give exactly the same result. To check, I used [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py) example and change the code once using `predict_proba` and once `decision_function`.

Specifically I changed:

```
probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
# Compute ROC curve and area the curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
```

to:

```
probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).decision_function(X[test])
# Compute ROC curve and area the curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_)
```

And both yield the exact same result as you can see in the images:

[image]

[image]

Yet this only counts for SVC where the distance to the decision plane is used to compute the probability - therefore no difference in the ROC.

In another [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) a specific line of code is relevant for this question:

```
if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
    Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
else:
    Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]
```

Therefore, deducing from the sklearn example, I would recommend you use the `decision_function` wherever possible and if not, use the probability provided by `predict_proba`.

Examples for algorithms which do not provide a `decision_function` in sklearn:

- `KNeighborsClassifier()`
- `RandomForestClassifier()`
- `GaussianNB()`

Comment: Why do you make that recommendation?  Based on that line of code from an example?  It's worth noting that if the probability is a monotonic function of the decision score (as it generally should be), then the results will be the same.

Comment: Good point. I tried to answer just deducing from code as emphasized in the answer. Basically the answer is specific to the package since i derive the recommendation from the source code, where the developers use the decision function with priority.

Comment: Over time, I've grown more and more suspicious of the sklearn developers decision making on things like this.  This is a pretty clear case of the wrong advice, as a decision rule that is not monotonic with respect to probabilities is inconsistent.  If the probability is a monotonic function of the decision function this is fine, but it still makes more conceptual sense to threshold the probabilities.  The only defense I can think of is if computation of the probability from the decision function is expensive.